# Single array input for multiple sorting methods

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to test the performances of my sorting methods using System commands such as `nanoTime`.

The issue I'm currently facing is that I have 4 different sorting methods, and I only accept a single array input. What would be the best way to test all sorting methods using that single array.

Is making copies with no reference point the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can (a) make copies to check all methods during a single run or you can (b) run your code several times with choose of the method for this input. the first approach seems to be simpler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int methods = 4;
    final int[] input = new int[0]; // or whatever you want.
    final long[] measures = new long[methods];

    for (int c = 0; c < methods; c++) {
        int[] copy = new int[input.length];
        System.arraycopy(input, 0, copy, 0, input.length);

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                // call method #0
                break;
            //...
            case 3:
                // call method #3
                break;
        }
        measures[c] = System.nanoTime() - start;
    }

    System.out.println("Measures: " + Arrays.toString(measures));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a temp array in each of the methods and sort that one so the original goes unchanged.

Here's how I picture it. This assumes you want to return the sorted array, but you may not have to if all you want to do is time the sort.

```
public String[] sort1(String[] arr){
    String[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.Length);
    // start counter
    // sort temp
    // end counter
    return temp;
}
```

And then somewhere in your main method you could call each of the sort methods with your original array, and it would never be changed.

I'm (admittedly) not an efficiency expert, and there may be a more efficient way than creating a copy of each array, but if this is just a small application to test your sorting speeds this should do everything you need it to.

**EDIT**

Here's one flow-of-control that came to mind that I think would help keep things most organized for you.

```
// Create array
public String[] myArray = {"Blah", "Blah", "Blah"};

// Have one sortArray() method that will take the array to be sorted, as well as the type of sort to be used.
public void sortArray(String[] arr, int arrayType){
   String[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.Length);

   // Switch based on sort type
   switch(arrayType){
      case 1:
         sort1(temp);
         break;
      case 2:
         sort2(temp);
         break;
      default:
         // Maybe raise exception about no available sort. Or just break.
         break;
   }
}

// Your main method can loop through each:
public static void Main(String[] args){
   int numSorts = 4; // Or whatever

   for(int i = 1; i <= numSorts; i++){
      sortArray(myArray, i);
   }
}
```

I'm sure much syntax will be adjusted to match your existing code, but I would create one sorting method that copies the input array, and in turn calls the necessary sorting method. Then, inside your main, you can loop through each sorting method you have. Inside each specific sorting method (`sort1(), sort2()`) I would start your timers there. Print to the console or a log, whatever you prefer.

Let me know if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think there would be a way around making multiple copies.

Comment: @someoldlady no problem! Yeah, you're still making a copy in some ways, but it's better than creating multiple copies of your input array which is just wasted lines of code. I think I have one idea to make this whole thing work nicely, I will edit question in a moment.

Comment: @Someoldlady I gave an edit to include an idea for how you can avoid repeating code. Let me know if you have questions, I think it will help.